Telegram WebApp при попытке зайти через андроид выдаёт ошибку
При входе в Telegram WebApp через бота выдаёт ошибку: Upstream connection error: unable to verify the first certificate. Причём если делать запрос из браузера или с других устройств всё ок. Сайт выдаётся через nginx

Решение:  В nginx вместо cert.pem надо задать fullchain.pem.
